# For which values of $p$ does the series $\sum_{k = 1}^\infty \frac{\exp(-p k)}{k^{1-p}}$ converge?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I discovered the following sequence,

$$\sum_{k = 1}^\infty \frac{\exp(-p k)}{k^{1-p}}$$

where $p \geq 0$

For certain values of $p$, this series is summable.

Does anyone know how to determine the range of $p$ for which this series is summable?

Comment: The corresponding heuristic to the precise answers given below is that $e^{-x}$ decays much faster than any negative polynomial power, and converges fast enough that it is alone integrable/summable on intervals like $[0.\infty)$. If you understand this, you can almost immediately identify whether commonly encountered integrals/series converge or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The integral test is useful here and note that
$$
\int_1^\infty x^{p-1}e^{-px} \ dx \le \int_0^\infty x^{p-1} e^{-px} \ dx
$$
which is the Gamma distribution and finite for all $p > 0$. Hence it converges for all $p > 0$. The case $p = 0$ is clearly divergent by the $p$-test.

Comment: Ok, I would not have been able to figure that out haha. Thanks!

Comment: No problem! Feel free to accept the answer if you don't have any other questions.

Answer (score 1):

What about the ratio test?

\begin{align*}
\limsup_{k\to\infty}\left|\frac{a_{k+1}}{a_{k}}\right| & = \limsup_{k\to\infty}\frac{\exp(-p(k+1))}{(k + 1)^{1-p}}\times\frac{k^{1-p}}{\exp(-pk)}\\\\
& = \limsup_{k\to\infty}\exp(-p)\left(\frac{k}{k+1}\right)^{1-p}\\\\
& = \exp(-p) < 1
\end{align*}

The last relation holds when $p > 0$. When $p = 0$, we obtain the harmonic series.

Based on the previous results, we conclude the proposed series converges according to the ratio test when $p > 0$ and diverges when $p = 0$ (due to the Condensation test, for example).

Hopefully this helps !